# Which or Who, Which should I use?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

I am confused about this fill in the blank questions. What should I use, *which* or *who*?

> Humans are the only factors in the ecosystem _____ are responsible for the changes in the ecology.

Comment: I'm not sure I like '... only factors Ø are responsible for ...' in the first place. 'Factor' already carries the sense of 'being responsible for / contributing to'.  I'd go with perhaps 'members', or rewrite to 'Detailed studies of the ecosystem have shown that humans are the sole cause of changes in the ecology.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the rule says use *who* when referring to people. In this case though the humans are not being treated as people, but merely as factors. I could write *Advanced tool-using hominids are the only factors which ...*, and I think most people would agree with *which* even though all advanced tool-using hominids are humans.

Therefore I would prefer *which* to *who*. Using *that* is a neat way of avoiding the question because it may be used for both human and non-human situations

Answer (score 0):

If your choice is limited, use *who* as suggested by Nima. (Edited: I too hastily wrote this, being influenced by the Scottish use of *factor* as a person. Otherwise I prefer *which*, referring to the non-human interpretation of *factor*).

Ideally, I would use *that are responsible...* because *are responsible for ...* is an essential clause defining *factors*. To remove the clause is to change the meaning of the sentence, and it is therefore essential and introduced by *that*.

There is a relevant and useful discussion of which/that in https://www.grammarly.com/blog/which-vs-that/

Edited: if you have time to pursue the *that*/*which* controversy, I refer you to *Fowler's Modern English Usage* (R W Burchfield, Third Edition, Oxford University Press, 1996); try the entry under "that (relative pronoun)".

Comment: There is a superstition (recorded in that grammarly blog) that you can't use _which_ in a restrictive clause. Oliver Kamm says in _Accidence will happen_: "One thing you won't find in style guides that advocate the _that/which_ rule is the slightest substantiation for it. You're supposed to accept it on trust, apparently. Don't bother. For centuries, great writers have used _which_ instead of _that_ in precisely the way that the sticklers condemn". It is true that we don't use _that_ in non-restrictive clauses. It is a myth that we shouldn't use _which_ in restrictive ones.

Comment: @Colin Fine The advice - for reasoned advice it is, rather than a rule - that you belittle as superstition comes from sources that deserve better of you. I have now given one of them in my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, Fowler couches it as a plea, and says "it wouold be idle to preetend that it is the practice either of most or of the best writers". Many would-be authorities since have presented it as a rule. Grammarly doesn't use the word "rule", but presents it as an unnuanced command.